# Php - make secure web application

Tags: php, security

I know there are already many posts on this topic but now i have a big confusion in how can i make secure web application.

Ok so i was making a registration page. There are some input fields like name, date of birth , city etc.
I have done validation for date , name and other fields.

But for countries, i have a dropdown list of countries in select tag which are generated from database.
And anyone can change its value using **inspect element** so how will i know that value is changed by inspect element.

Ex. If user selects `<option value="IN">India</option>` , I am getting `IN` in php but if user change it  to `<option value="hacker">India</option>` i am getting value as `hacker`.

So how can i check that value is changed and what are the good steps to make secure web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side, on the page that receives the form submission, you could check if the received response is in your list of countries and reject if not.

```
if (!in_array($_POST['country'], $countries)) echo "Invalid country";
```

I would have a broader question about why this is necessary, though. If users are free to choose their country from the list, why would one of them change the value? If you're concerned about SQL injection attacks, you should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I am using pdo prepared statements but it can't detect value is changed or not but in_array is useful in this case...thanks